# Makefile - error while compiling - file not found

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

in my makefile Im trying to compile a headerfile and a main program that tests my function. but for some reason my main program "testloadgc" isn't found when I try to compile. any help in understanding this would be appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Text copies and pastes nicely. That is better than a screenshot for simple things like this. That said your problem is simply that you got your command wrong. Look at the compilation command again and look at how the options work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't copy the text as you posted an image (worse, a *link* (that may disappear) to an image), but the faulty line goes something like

```
icc -o objectfile1.o objectfile2.o objectfile3.o outputfile
```

The problem here is that you try to link the files `objectfile2.o`, `objectfile3.o` *and* `outputfile` together and name the resulting executable file `objectfile1.o`. The error tells you that the file `outputfile` can't be found for the linker to read, because it's not supposed to be existing yet.

The `-o` options must be followed directly by the output file name:

```
icc -o outputfile objectfile1.o objectfile2.o objectfile3.o
```